# How to write the differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-modeling

A tank consists of $50$ litre of fresh water . Two litres of brine each litre containing $5$ gms of dissolved salt are run into tank per minute . The mixture is kept uniform by stirring and runs out at the rate of $1$ litre per minute . If $m$ grams of salt are present in the tank after $t$ minute , we have to expess $m$ in terms of $t$   .

I tried it and write it as 
$$
m = 10t - \frac{10t}{50 + t}
$$

Comment: this is not a de.

Comment: @KonKan it is a de as m = dm / dt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We measure the time $t$ in minutes, the  volume $v$ of the liquid in litre and the amount of salt in gram.

At the beginning ($t=0$) the tank contains $50$ litre, so 
$$v(0)=50 \tag{1}$$
The volume of liquid in the tank after $t$ minutes is $v(t)$ litre. $\Delta t$ minutes later, at the moment $t+\Delta t$ the tank contains 
$$v(t+\Delta t) = v(t)+ 2\Delta t - \Delta t \tag{2}$$
litre.
From this we get
$$\frac{v(t+\Delta t) - v(t)}{\Delta t} = 1 \tag{3}$$
Assuming $\Delta t \to 0$ this gives
$$v'(t)=1\tag{4}$$
From $(1)$ and $(4)$ we get
$$v(t)=50+t\tag{5}$$
Of course one can get this result without using a differential equation.

$m(t)$ is the amount of salt (in gram) at the moment $t$ (in minutes) in the tank. We have
$$m(0)=0\tag{6}$$
gram salt in the tank at $t=0$ (fresh water without salt)
The concentration of salt at the moment $t$ is the amount of salt divided by the amount of liquid, so the concentration (in gram/litre) is $\frac{m(t)}{v(t)}$.
From $t$ to $t+\Delta t$ we will loose  $\frac{m(t)}{v(t)}\Delta t$ grams of salt (this is only an approximation) and get $2\cdot 5\Delta t$ of salt. So for small $\Delta t$ we have  approximately
$$m(t+\Delta t)=m(t)+2\cdot 5 \Delta t-\frac{m(t)}{v(t)} \Delta t \tag{7}$$
Dividing $(7)$ by $\Delta t$ we get
$$\frac{m(t+\Delta t)-m(t)}{\Delta t}=10-\frac{m(t)}{v(t)}\tag{8}$$

Now we replace $v(t)$ by $(5)$ and let $\Delta t \to 0$ in $(7)$ and we finally get the differential equation

$$m'(t)=10-\frac{m(t)}{50+t}\tag{9}$$
with the initial condition $(6)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let use denote $m(t)$ as the amount of salt presented in the tank at time $t$.

Observe the differential equation is given by
\begin{align}
\text{Rate of Change salt in tank} = \text{ Rate of salt entering the tank}-\text{ Rate of salt existing the tank}
\end{align}
or more mathematically we have
\begin{align}
\frac{dm}{dt} = 10 \text{ g}\cdot \text{min}^{-1} - (1\text{ L}\cdot\text{ min}^{-1})\times \frac{m(t)}{V(t)} \text{ g}\cdot \text{ L}^{-1}.
\end{align}

Comment: That means I have written correct

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: the equation written by me is it not correct ? Is it not same as yours ?

Comment: They are definitely not the same. You do not have a differential equation.

Comment: in mine equation m = dm / dt

Comment: even then it's not the same.

Comment: Then can you please give me correct equation.

Comment: I did in the post.

Comment: But we have to find mass present at any time for that how we will solve this

Comment: Please look carefully at my equation. You should see a mass term on the right hand side of the equation as well.

Comment: for example we have to find mass present at 5 minute , then how will we find that and what is that